# @if (User.IsInRole("System Administrator","Administrator"))

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to give access to System Administrator and Administrator but when I am writing 
 @if (User.IsInRole("System Administrator","Administrator")) getting error(no overload for method'IsINRole' take 2 arguments)allthough on controller it is working

[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "System Administrator,Administrator")]
    public class CategoriesController : Controller

I there other a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass multiple roles to the `IsInRole` function. But you can use the `||` functionality in c# as below.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("System Administrator") || User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot!!